# IQ Test Common Question

Tags: pattern, visual

Need help to understand the answer C) on this question. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One explanation:

> The diagonal line moves around the squares two blocks each time (i.e., it alternates between top right and bottom left)
>
>  The dots move one and two spaces, clockwise, each time
>  From the first to the second image, the top left dot moves one space clockwise, while the bottom left dot moves two spaces clockwise
>  From the second to the third image, this pattern results in them sharing a square
>  From the third to the fourth image (c), this pattern results in one dot sharing a square with the diagonal